# Query to find lakes that are in multiple states

Tags: mysql, database, recursive-query

I have tables to hold information about Lakes, Counties, and States. I also have a table called LakeLocation that is simple a pair of foreign keys of a LakeID and CountyID, so I can know where they are. And each county has a StateName inside it.

A high-level view of it all is something like this:

`Lake = {id,name,...}`

`County = {id, name, StateName ....}`

`State = {name, ...}`

`LakeLocation = {LakeID, CountyID}`

I am trying to find out which states have lakes that are in more than one state. An example is Lake Tahoe which crosses four county lines and two state lines. I know that I will need a recursive query, but I only understand those for simple one table child/parent type relationships. Not this.

How can I design a query that does what I need? Thanks

Comment: Sample data would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a `group by` to know what are the lakes

```
  SELECT LakeID
  FROM LakeLocation 
  GROUP BY LakeID
  HAVING COUNT(CountyID) > 1
```

Then if you want lake names

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Lake 
  WHERE LakeID IN (<previous query>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved my issue. My actual issue was more complicated, and this part was the biggest issue, I did not want to ask everything straight out because I want to figure it out myself.